# CLLocation services. Added plist keys and request permission, yet still not working for IOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, plist, cllocationmanager

I've checked other topics on stack overflow and done the same changes.  Apple docs doesn't seem to have anything I've missed either.

Copied from my plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Used for finding users in your area. &quot;Stealth mode&quot; can be used if you would like not users to see your location on the map</string>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Used for finding users in your area. &quot;Stealth mode&quot; can be used if you would like not users to see your location on the map</string>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

My code:

```
+(AsyncBackgroundUpdateManager*)getInstance
{
    if (instance == nil)
    {
        instance = [[AsyncBackgroundUpdateManager alloc] init];
    }

    return instance;
}

-(id)init
{
    if (instance != nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"WARNING: You should not call init on an AsyncBackgroundUpdateManager, you should use the static \"getInstance\" method.@");
    }

    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
        {
            if (locManager == nil)
            {
                locManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
            }

            locManager.delegate = self;
            locManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
            locManager.distanceFilter = 100;//Meters
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Location not enabled");
        }
    }

    return self;
}


// -------------------------------------------------------------
// Controlling updating process
// -------------------------------------------------------------

-(void)start
{
    //Get locations permission
    if ([locManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
        [locManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        switch ([CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]) {
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied:
                NSLog(@"Location services are not allowed");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined:
                NSLog(@"Location services are undecided");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse:
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized:
                NSLog(@"Location services are allowed");
                break;
            case kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted:
                NSLog(@"Location services restricted?");
                break;
        }

    }
    [locManager startUpdatingLocation];
    theTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:120 target:self selector:@selector(doUpdate) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}
```

Called by line:

```
[[AsyncBackgroundUpdateManager getInstance] start];
```

I've verified that the location manager is initialized via a breakpointing on the the alloc/init line.

I've verified that requestWhenInUseAuthorization is called by breakpointing on that line.

I'm never prompted for location services, and a breakpoint in did update location is never called.

In my device's settings, my app doesn't appear to request permissions for location.

This is outputed: Location services are undecided

**Edit:**

From the comments:
The start method is called in the main thread
The device I'm running it on has location services enabled, and is running ios 8.  This worked prior to ios 8.

**Edit:**

When executing the code provided by user IOS in a new testing view controller I get the same results.  Here is a screenshot to show that the call is being called.  (I stepped the debugger to that line, starting where you can see the breakpoint)
[image: shows that line is called]

Comment: Is `-start` called on a background thread or the main thread?

Comment: If you're using a simulator, have you turned on location services for the simulator?

Comment: @jszumski Start is called in the main thread.

Comment: @Zolnoor It's not in the simulator, it's a device, and it's location settings are on.  Regardless, I think that should make the "locationServicesEnabled" fail, not prevent the user from being prompted.

Comment: Since you are running on a device and not a simulator, have you reset Location Privacy settings under Settings > General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy

Comment: @rmp  These are usefull settings to know.  I appreciate it, and your help.  Apparently it seems my issue was some sort of stupid bug, not that.  But you're reset help assisted me to better debug and such.  I didn't need to reset the services, as the popup had never appeared, once I fixed it it popped up on the device without resetting it.

Comment: Awesome glad you got it working!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project has an InfoPlist.strings file.
This is in addition to the normal AppName-Info.plist file.

Entering the keys into the normal plist file does nothing, though it caused me to pass the test provided by user IOS, and other users.  I had to enter the keys into the InfoPlist.strings file.

After a quick look at apple docs:  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/AboutInformationPropertyListFiles.html

It seems that the InfoPlist.strings file is part of normalization.  You have multiple versions of the same file based on language.  As apple says:

> The routines that look up key values in the Info.plist file take the
>   user’s language preferences into account and return the localized
>   version of the key (from the appropriate InfoPlist.strings file) when
>   one exists. If a localized version of a key does not exist, the
>   routines return the value stored in the Info.plist file.

So, it does not seem to me as if this functionality is working the way I understand based on what that says...

But, regardless, adding the keys to both my Info.plist and my InfoPlist.strings file seems to fix the problem.

**EDIT:**
It looks like I am incorrect in terms of the behavior I am experiencing.

My InfoPlist.strings file contained an old key:

```
<key>NSLocationUsageDescription</key>
<string>Used for finding users in your area. &quot;Stealth mode&quot; can be used if you would like not users to see your location on the map</string>
```

Adding both keys caused it to error, and removing both keys while having them in the original Info.plist file fixed it.

My compiler seems to have issues on my mac.  On another project, a class wasn't compiled correctly with it's parent class.  I built and rebuilt over and over again, and I had no idea why the class wasn't showing as a subclass of it's parent as it should have.  Cleaning the project, and rebuilding fixed it.

This issue may have been related to that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting `'kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined` as your status then location services have not been set for your app. You need to get permission before calling `startUpdatingLocation`

Try something like this:

```
//request permissions
if([myLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]){
    //iOS 8 and above permission request
    //get current status
    CLAuthorizationStatus currentStatus=[CLLocationManager authorizationStatus];

    //if undetermined, ask for permission
    if (currentStatus == (kCLAuthorizationStatusNotDetermined)) {
        //request permission
        [myLocationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    }
}
```

Comment: I call the requestWhenInUseAuthorization method prior to outputing the status.

Comment: CLLocationManager has changed since ios 7.0, you must get permission before using it. If you don't have permission the methods will never fire.  Also, you only have one chance to present the user with the request and that is when the status is returned as `notDetermined` then and only then will the request for permission display an alert to the user allowing them to allow it.  After that, you have to do it maually via your own alert.

Comment: Yes, but if you look at my code, I request permission in the start function.  I have verified that my code reaches that line.

Comment: And it is still listed as "not determined"  as I think I mentioned, the setting for location does not appear for my app in the settings.

Comment: Yes, your code will reach that line, however, if the status of your app is not `notDetermined` it will pass right over that line and do nothing. As mentioned above, you only have one shot at asking for permission. After that you need to check the status and then request permission manually by presenting an alert asking the user to change the permission.  You can test this by resting your simulator content  under File> Reset Content and Settings and then building and running your app.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling the app has now effect.  And the setting to change to permission does not exist in the settings.  So they user could not change the setting if I did alert them of it.  I'll try the simulator thing though.

Comment: You need to rest your simulator. iOS Simulator > Reset Content & Settings. Uninstalling will not reset your app permission settings

Comment: I did that in the simulator.  I got prompted for push notifications as expected, but not location settings.  I verified the request permission line was being called as well.